# Is it possible to use megacli to copy from one partition to another?

Tags: megaraid, megacli

Except "dd" and "rsync", is it possible to directly use the megacli command to copy one partition to another? I am using h310 raid controller, and it seems not working well using "dd" or "rsync", which sometimes results in firemware failure, reset and fault state etc. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Are you using Linux? Can you tell us why you think `rsync` and `dd` don't work well?

Comment: Sometimes, those commands may fail with reason like "Broken pipe". When I check /var/log/messages, usually it first shows message like "25 commands wait to complete", then megasas seems to enter some fault state but not able to get ready, then everything just hangs up there until timeout. Is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. MegaCLI is not aware of partitions, it just manages the disks as a whole.